# How to postpone stackoverflowError IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: memory, intellij-idea, stack-overflow, heap-memory

I found a solution where I didn't have to increaseany memory size,

```
var count = 0

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    repeater()
}
fun repeater(){
    a()
    repeater()
}
fun a(){
    if(count%2000==0 && count !=0){
        count++
        return
    }
    count++
    println(count)
}
```

this actually works for some reason.
Testing it with the simple println() it went up from the 1100 to over 400k.
 I just recently started programming and I dont quite understand this, also testing it in my program where 2 bots play against each other it did increase the matches they could play from 400 to about 4000-5000.
(I had to play with different 
modulators(?) to find the optimal
)
I also tested using more than one repeater and modulator-ifs, but I couldn't find any rule, with some additional it was way better, with some even worse.

//this is the original question:

I want the error to be thrown later, so if it were thrown after 1000 recursive calls I would want it to be thrown after 2000 or more.
Increasing heap memory or memory doesn't change it. Always around 11000 calls for me.

```
var count = 0   
fun a(){  count++  println(count)  a() }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increase the thread stack size using the `-Xss` JVM argument.

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/java.html):

> **-Xsssize**
>
> Sets the thread stack size (in bytes). Append the letter k or K to indicate KB, m or M to indicate MB, g or G to indicate GB. The default value depends on the platform:
>
> - Linux/ARM (32-bit): 320 KB
> - Linux/i386 (32-bit): 320 KB
> - Linux/x64 (64-bit): 1024 KB
> - OS X (64-bit): 1024 KB
> - Oracle Solaris/i386 (32-bit): 320 KB
> - Oracle Solaris/x64 (64-bit): 1024 KB
>
> The following examples set the thread stack size to 1024 KB in different units:
>
> ```
> -Xss1m
> -Xss1024k
> -Xss1048576
> ```
>
> This option is equivalent to `-XX:ThreadStackSize`.